# How to escape from (END) in terminal for binding.pry

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm stuck inside of a pry session.

There was a long list of text which I had to scroll through and now I can't seem to escape.

I have tried `ctrl + c` and `ctrl + v` and `esc` and `enter`. Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try 'q', the binding for less. But it may depends on which default pager you use.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it seems pry had bugged out, and after trying @kik's suggestion,

I resorted to:

- typing `exit` and hitting enter, then
- `rails c` to get back into the console.

Nothing else I could find seemed to work